# Python Grequests xml responses

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, python-multithreading, grequests

Quick question with grequests since the documentation for it is rather sparse.
What is the best way to return xml reponse from the request sent?  I'm having trouble finding a way to get a response back other than the status codes.  Could someone point me in the right direction?  Can grequests even return xml responses? Should I just use requests and do the threading myself?
Heres the documentation code

```
import grequests

urls = [
'http://www.heroku.com',
'http://python-tablib.org',
'http://httpbin.org',
'http://python-requests.org',
'http://kennethreitz.com'
]
rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
grequests.map(rs)
```

So my question is how do you go from mapping the request to actually getting xml responses?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Iterator over the return value of `grequests.map`. Each  yielded item is response object. You can get the content using `content` property.

For example:

```
rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
for response in grequests.map(rs):
    print('{}: {}'.format(response.url, len(response.content)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only returns the URL plus a code at the end. For example: `http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/thesaurus/xml/political?key=mykey' returns
` http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/thesaurus/xml/political?key=mykey: 261 `

Comment: @user2758113, It is not code. It's the length of the content. Replace `len(response.content)` with `response.content`. I used `len` because printing content prints too much.